# byte[] to string conversion doesn't seem to work the way I want

Tags: c#, text

I'm trying to display the content of a byte array in a text file.

This is my code:

```
        var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\B323.txt");
        writer.Write(data.ToString());
        writer.Close();
        writer.Dispose();
```

data is a byte[] array.

The output is "System.Byte[]",why?

I'm trying to display the content of this array,where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `byte[].ToString()` that just returns `System.Byte[]`. How were you intending the byte array to be converted? There are any number of ways of converting the bytes to a string.

If you want it as a "hex dump" you could you `BitConverter.ToString(byte[])` which will produce output such as

```
5B-3E-5D
```

Is that what you're after? If you *actually* want to just write the bytes to a file, because they *already* represent encoded text, then you should use a `FileStream` instead and write them directly.

(Other points as asides: you should use a `using` statement to handle the writer; you don't need to call close because you're already disposing; `File.WriteAllText` is a simpler way of doing this to start with.)

Comment: I only wanted to know why it display "System.Byte[]".Yes that's what I want,but I use LINQ to display a space instead of a dash between the characters.I just wanted to know why it display System.Byte[]

Comment: The default implementation of `Object.ToString()` is to dump the type name. Array doesn't override this.

Comment: Thanks Jon! How is the progress of the second edition of your book? I can't wait!

Comment: It's coming along slowly :) Hopefully I'll be able to give information about "early access" fairly soon...

Answer (score 3):

Calling `ToString` on `data` will turn it into a textual representation (the same you will see in the Watch or Locals window when debugging).

You can either just write `data` to the stream, or use one of the functions located in `System.Text.Encoding` to convert your byte[] to a string.

Answer (score 3):

The default ToString() implementation just echoes the class name. You probably want one of the Encoding.GetString() methods, like [ASCIIEncoding.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358574.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Which do you want to do? Write the data as bytes or as their text representation?

Binary:

```
FileStream fS = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + @"\B323.txt");
BinaryWriter bW = new BinaryWriter(fS);
bW.Write(data);
fS.Close();
```

Or

Text Representation:

```
var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\B323.txt");
writer.Write(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want the array to be represented in the text file, perhaps something like these:

```
// 12-34-AB
writer.Write(BitConverter.ToString(data));

// 1234AB
writer.Write(BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", string.Empty));

// 0x1234AB
writer.Write("0x" + BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", string.Empty));

// [ 12, 34, AB ]
writer.Write("[ " + BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", ", ") + " ]");

// [ 0x12, 0x34, 0xAB ]
writer.Write("[ 0x" + BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", ", 0x") + " ]");
```